# Is there a preexisting Javascript function to read "2009-09-16T11:10:00" as a date?

Tags: javascript, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert datetime microformat to local time in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436374/how-can-i-convert-datetime-microformat-to-local-time-in-javascript)

Im writing up an ajax application where i have to interpret this date "2009-09-16T11:10:00" and output another string to something more readable.

Comment: Yup - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436374/how-can-i-convert-datetime-microformat-to-local-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this js library:
http://www.datejs.com

Pretty good and recognizes different date formats. You can also test your date right on the front page.

Answer (score 3):

That's the ISO 8601 date format. There's an example [here](http://anentropic.wordpress.com/2009/06/25/javascript-iso8601-parser-and-pretty-dates/). If that doesn't suit your needs then a [quick google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+ISO+8601+date) should help.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't a built-in function for doing that. You'd have to parse it yourself. Maybe something like this:

```
var s = "2009-09-16T11:10:00";
var tokens = s.split(/[\-T:]/);
var date = new Date(tokens[0], tokens[1] - 1, tokens[2],
    tokens[3], tokens[4], tokens[5], 0);
```

Then access the date string with:

```
alert(date.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the custom and clean solution but dateJS seems to be a better solution for my project. thanks!