# Date difference in javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am querying facebook graph api. It returns date in following format: `2012-01-23T23:52:29+0000`.

I need to find difference of dates of this type in javascript. It's not a valid date in javascript ( by `Date.parse()` or `new Date()` )

I am thinking of replacing `'T'` with `' '` (a space), `'-'` with `'/'` and `'+0000'` with `''` (empty string). Is this the only way? Or am I missing something here?

Also, if this is the only way, can someone give me a regex to replace all in one go?

**Execution speed is my main concern.**

Comment: Does speed really matter *that* much? (If so, it would be interesting to see a jsperformance test-case for it.) The time format shown is ISO8601 (keyword), btw.

Comment: When you say speed is the main factor, do you mean execution speed? If so, are you seeing any performance issues?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a date value in UTC format to a date object in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498578/how-can-i-convert-a-date-value-in-utc-format-to-a-date-object-in-javascript)

Comment: A search for "Javascript ISO 8601" reveals: https://github.com/csnover/js-iso8601

Also: http://anentropic.wordpress.com/2009/06/25/javascript-iso8601-parser-and-pretty-dates/

Comment: Thanks for timeformat.

By speed, I meant the calculation must be fast.
I am doing 3-4 javascript replace() here. Isnt there any way faster than this ?

Comment: @PhilipFourie , Yes that questions solves my problem. Thanks alot guys. 'Pst', 'Josh' thanks for your time. Github one seems short and nice.

Comment: If a general sense, if you have a known input format that JS won't handle you can easily create a JS date manually by using `.substr()` to extract the pieces from your input. As far as execution speed, several replaces won't be a problem on a string that is only 24 characters long...

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for editing and your suggestion. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert datetime microformat to local time in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436374/how-can-i-convert-datetime-microformat-to-local-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say yes to replacing `-` with `/`, since that's that the ISO-whatever standard dictates (Facebook likes to screw things around, like `<meta>` tags with `property` attributes instead of `name` like they should be).

Keep the timezone part, since JS understands that and will handle it accordingly.

Overall, you want `new Date(input.replace(/-/g,'/'));`.

In response to comments, a better (more complete) solution would be:

```
new Date(input.replace(/-/g,'/').replace("T"," ").replace(/\+[0-9]+$/,''));
```

Comment: It throws invalid date in firefox 9.0. Works in chrome though

Comment: Do you have a regex for firefox too ?

Comment: `new Date(input.replace(/-/g,'/').replace(/T|\+[0-9]+/g,''));`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

ISO 8601 have '-' in place of '/'. Its standard. This time, facebook does not screw.

Firefox example is not working. 'T' should be replaced with ' ' not ''. 

Thanks Kolink, you made me realise that regex it not magic. I too can learn it. I thought regex can do all replacements in one go. So fool of me :(

Comment: Huh, insteresting. So the browsers are all wrong? Strange... Starting to wish `Date.parse()` were as good as PHP's `strtotime()`...

Comment: can you edit your original answer to suit firefox too, so that I can mark it as answer ?

Comment: Done - note that I've put the `T` replacement as a string replacement, since there's only one T and it can't be anything else there.